# object oriented JS drop list?

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, html-select

i've created a button using OO JS which will be used to update something later on. I would also like to add a drop down menu/select list to my web app. The code i used for my button is:

```
    var AddButton = function(label){
    var _dom_element = document.createElement("input");
        _dom_element.type = "button";
        _dom_element.value = label;

        _dom_element.onclick = function(){
            //click_action.call(null);
            alert("Im Clicked");
        };
        this.getDomElement = function() {
            return _dom_element;
        }
    }
```

How do I change this code so it becomes a drop down menu/select list?

My best guess is that _dom_element.type = "select"; or something along those lines, however i havent got a clue what the actual type should equal.

Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: No, an `<input type="select" />` element does not exist. You see which types exist here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/Input. If you want some kind of combo button, then there are multiple ways to do this. I suggest to have a look at how popular libraries implement it, e.g. [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#buttonDropdowns).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
var AddSelect = function(options){
    var _dom_element = document.createElement("select");

    for ( var i = 0; i < options.length; i++ ) {
        var _option = document.createElement("option");
            _option.value = options[i];
            _option.innerHTML = options[i];

        _dom_element.appendChild(_option);
    }

    document.body.appendChild(_dom_element);

    _dom_element.onclick = function(){
        //click_action.call(null);
        //alert("Im Clicked");
    };
    this.getDomElement = function() {
        return _dom_element;
    }
}

AddSelect(['option1', 'option2', 'option3']);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hn5Ws/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var AddSelect = function(options){
    var _dom_element = document.createElement("select");

    for ( var i = 0; i < options.length; i++ ) {
        var _option = document.createElement("option");
            _option.value = options[i];
            _option.innerHTML = options[i];

        _dom_element.appendChild(_option);
    }

    document.body.appendChild(_dom_element);

    _dom_element.onclick = function(){
        //click_action.call(null);
        //alert("Im Clicked");
    };
    this.getDomElement = function() {
        return _dom_element;
    }
}

AddSelect(['option1', 'option2', 'option3']);
```